# Palindrome Test

Tags: c, palindrome

Is there anything wrong with this palindrome test?
It was written in C language.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int a, b, c, d, e, div1, div2;
    printf("Enter a 5 digits number. (Please put space every time you type each digit.) \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e);

    div1= a%e;
    div2= b%d;

    if(div1==0 && div2==0){
    printf("The number %d%d%d%d%d is a palindrome.", a, b, c, d, e);
    }

    else if(div1!=0 || div2!=0){
    printf("The number %d%d%d%d%d is not a palindrome.", a, b, c, d, e);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's your code, your requirements, so *you* tell *us* if there's something wrong with it, and if so, what.

Comment: If *you* don't see a problem with it, you are at a wrong place. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: To clarify, what is "palindrome" here?

Comment: "Is there anything wong?" @MikeCAT mentioned two "minor" points in his answer. But robust code contains **NO** "minor" points, especially `scanf` *must* be tested every time. Here is a point of style: `else if(div1!=0 || div2!=0)` unnecessarily repeats the test you already established as "false" when a simple `else` will do. In general, that type of thing leads to code bloat, high maintenance, and poor readability.

Answer (score 4):

Yes

---

Typing `6 4 3 2 3` would make the program output that its a palindrome..

Rather then

```
div1= a%e;  // a%e is 0 even when a = 6 and e = 3
div2= b%d;  // b%d is 0 even when b = 4 and d = 2

if(div1==0 && div2==0)
```

*a%e is 0 even when a = 6 and e = 3*

*b%d is 0 even when b = 4 and d = 2*

---

You need to do the check

```
if(a == e && b == d)
```

---

As a side note. This is not the proper way to check for palindrome.

Check out [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-number-is-palindrome/) link for the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

For example, If the input is

```
1 0 1 0 1
```

This program will invoke undefined behavoir because the second operand of `%` operator becomes zero, and typically will crash.

Another example: this program will consider `5 4 3 2 1` as a palindrome.

Why on the earth are there weird division? Why couldn't they be simple

```
div1= a==e;
div2= b==d;
```

? (the name `divn` is now not good)

There are also some minor wrong point such as using `main()` instead of `int main(void)` and not checking if the `scanf()` successfully read 5 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. The test for palindromicity is `a == e && b == d`.
2. The behaviour of `n % 0` is *undefined*. So zero `d` or `e` will give you trouble.

Luckily (2) goes away when refactoring your code to 1.